# Docker: cannot create directory ‘/opt/jfrog/artifactory/logs’: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, docker

I am trying to configure a docker image to run with a mounted volume, for persistence. The image is the official artifactory one. It seems odd to me that it will stop after creating several directories with a "Permission denied".

As I inspect the mounted volume, I can see that several folders were created when the image attempted to go up. And the database config is also ok.

Digging a bit, this guy seems to have permission issues artifactory:artifactory

However, I cannot go any further to the point I am able to explain or correct the problem.

```
---
Found java executable in JAVA_HOME (/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64)
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/jfrog/artifactory/logs’: Permission denied

** Could not create dir /opt/jfrog/artifactory/logs/catalina


Preparing to run Artifactory in Docker
=====================================
2017-03-17 12:51:17   [42 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking open files and processes limits

2017-03-17 12:51:17   [45 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Current max open files is 65536

2017-03-17 12:51:17   [57 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Current max open processes is unlimited

2017-03-17 12:51:17   [67 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking if /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory is mounted

2017-03-17 12:51:18   [72 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory is mounted

2017-03-17 12:51:18   [78 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Setting up data directories if missing

2017-03-17 12:51:18   [88 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Create artifactory user if missing

2017-03-17 12:51:18   [94 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] User artifactory already exists

2017-03-17 12:51:18  [101 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking permissions on /opt/jfrog/artifactory

2017-03-17 12:51:18  [110 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] /opt/jfrog/artifactory is already owned by artifactory:artifactory.

2017-03-17 12:51:18  [114 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking permissions on /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory

2017-03-17 12:51:18  [120 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory is owned by root:root. Setting to artifactory:artifactory.

2017-03-17 12:51:18  [246 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking DB_TYPE

2017-03-17 12:51:18  [249 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] DB_TYPE is set to mysql

2017-03-17 12:51:18  [177 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] DB_HOST is set to x.y.s.w

2017-03-17 12:51:18  [179 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking if need to copy mysql configuration

2017-03-17 12:51:18  [182 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/db.properties already exists. Making sure it's set to mysql... 

2017-03-17 12:51:18  [185 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/db.properties already set to mysql

2017-03-17 12:51:18  [154 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Waiting for DB mysql to be ready on 104.196.117.4/3306 within 30 seconds

2017-03-17 12:51:18  [159 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] DB mysql up in 0 seconds
---
Found java executable in JAVA_HOME (/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64)
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/jfrog/artifactory/logs’: Permission denied
```

Comment: a) there is no "official" image for `artifactory`, b) you didn't provide us anything to help you!

Comment: a) there is
https://bintray.com/jfrog
b) what else could I provide to help?

Comment: Seems I am not alone here: http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2016/04/12/why-i-chose-nexus-over-artifactory-when-using-docker/

Comment: digging more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020318/why-docker-container-cant-create-folders-in-mounted-folders

Comment: I have the same issue, did you fix it ?

Comment: After a while I figure it out. My case was due to the file system. More specifically fuse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when sharing an nfs mount point as a volume. This resolved it:

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

Hope that fixes your issue!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I have figure out the way by which your container will run without any problem.

Just dail# 
sudo chmod -R 777 /data

because /data is volume mount for each container and artifactory container was failing due to permission denied

containers name
1. docker.bintray.io/jfrog/nginx-artifactory-pro
2. docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro
3. docker.bintray.io/postgres

after changes wait for 2-3 min

Comment: A recursive chmod to 777 is usually a bad idea.

Comment: chmod 777 = I don't want to manage permissions :)